# Help Understanding Opamp Topology (Infinite Gain Multiple feedback with Resistor to Gnd?)

Tags: filter, feedback, active-filter

I ran across the following band-pass circuit and I'm not entirely sure what `R14` is doing here. The following is a screenshot:

[image]

For some context, the supply is a dual rail +/- 3V3 and the input is a 100 mV peak-peak, zero-centered sine wave (called "X in act" here). The input comes from a an opamp differential-in-single-ended-out, unity-gain buffer stage. The frequency of interest is centered at 20 kHz.

For the most part it looks to me like an ["infinite gain multiple  feedback" bandpass](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/filter_7.html) topology but there's an extra resistor `R14` in there that's throwing me off.

Can somebody please explain what the purpose of that might be and how I might go about analyzing it? Is it something practical I'm missing?

Let me know if there's anything I missed or can add for reference. Otherwise, thanks in advance!

Comment: R14 is required to meet a **GAIN** spec, as well as **frequency** and **Q** spec. It is assumed that the signal source coming into R13 is a voltage source having 0 ohms equivalent resistance. So R13 and R14 are essentially in parallel for AC analysis. You can swap R13 with R14 if you want more gain. Or, if you can stand having even more gain, eliminate R14 and make R13 5170 ohms. Just be sure to drive it with a voltage source having low internal resistance.

Comment: The resistor R14 is NOT necessary - however, without R14 the quality factor cannot be tuned without touchung the midband gain Am. The relation is Am=Q²(1+C10/C9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antonio shows that varying R14 can shift resonant frequency. Look closely, resonant bandwidth changes.
As frequency drops with higher values of R14, Q is lower.

If you want frequency to remain constant and Q to remain constant too, then the parallel combination of R13 || R14 should remain constant. You can vary gain by varying their ratio, and still keep R13 || R14 constant (5170 ohms). 
When R13 is set to 5170 ohms, R14 becomes infinite, and disappears.

Here are three versions, all having same resonant frequency, and same resonant bandwidth. Gain varies up to a maximum of nearly 5.5 when R13 = 5170. You can have any gain less than 5.5 by including R14 and adjusting R13 || R14 to 5170[image: 3 versions each with different gain, but constant frequency, Q]:

Answer (score 1):

R14 (my R2) is very useful. Displace the center frequency "bandpass" filter.

[image]

Updated info:
One should see "analog filters handbook chapter8" from Analog Devices,
page 8.76 fig 8.54, and page 8.94 fig 8.72.

[image]

Comment: (-15) ... Wow...didn't know some were so "stubborn"? Remember ... "train", "help" and "learn" ... newbies.